# Is it possible to save an object while saving another object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
public class RexorDTO {
    private Rexor rexor; //an object without an id, I create it in the usual way via save
    private Transit transit; //without id
    private Service service;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "rexor_srv")
public class RexorSrv {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Service service;
    @OneToOne
    private Transit transit;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Rexor rexor;
}
```

Can I, after saving rexor, save transit while saving rexorsrv?

```
    rexor = rexorRepository.save(rexor);

    rexorSrvRepository.save(
            new RexorSrv(
                    rexorDTO.getService(),
                    rexorDTO.getTransit(),
                    rexor)
            );
```

object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Comment: Did yu try this ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: Dont forgot constructor and getters/setter

Comment: get/set standard generated, and he swears that the transit was not created

Comment: Do yu have  constructors in RexorDTO and in Transit?

Comment: the constructor is also generated

Comment: Any errors in logs?

Comment: only object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing